# How to assign a mongodb query result to a variable?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Now I connect Node.js with mongodb and query databse using express. Say there is schema called `Animal`, which has an array field called `traits`. When I query:

```
db.animals.distinct("traits")
```

I got the result as:

```
['playful', 'funny', 'lazy', 'loyal']
```

Is it possible that I pass this result to a variable for later use? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you could store them in a session,  cookie or may be at Redis..and then retrieve when needed

Comment: You mean I can code like `document.cookie = Animal.distinct("traits")`. Then I might retrieve it back using `var traits = document.cookie`. Is it right?

Comment: Did the answer worked..???

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can assign query result to variable. like this:

```
var a;
db.collection('animals', function(err, collection) {
    collection.distinct("traits", function(err, results) {
        a = results;
        console.log(results);
    });
});
```

Comment: But I want to use this variable out of callback function, not inside it.

Answer (score 0):

first install [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-sessions) by `npm install client-sessions`

call this in your main js page

```
  var session = require('client-sessions');
```

give definition

```
app.use(session({
  cookieName: 'session',
  secret: 'random_string_goes_here',
  duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
  activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000,
}));
```

Store the results in session called animals

```
    app.post('/getAnimals', function(req, res) {    
     // inside your DB query callback{}
       req.session.animals=  db.animals.distinct("traits")                       
   })
```

Retrieving data from session when required

```
console.log(req.session.animals);   //will give
['playful', 'funny', 'lazy', 'loyal']

console.log(req.session.animals[0]);  // will give first element
playful
```

Let me know if this solution solved your issue :) ?

Comment: First, thanks for your prompt response. But it didn't work for me. On `console.log(req.session.animals);`, the log shows `Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  mongooseCollection:
   NativeCollection {
     collection: Collection { s: [Object] },
     opts: { bufferCommands: true, capped: false },
     name: 'animals',....`. How do I know the client session start correctly? Because I tried `var traits = Animal.distinct.("traits"); console.log(traits)`before, it gave me the same result.